# Save userinput from an Activity after calling finish()

Tags: android, android-activity

In my Android Application, I have an Activity that gets the user's full name. When the next Activity is called, the former goes into a pause state and I have:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

If the user hits the back button, the application should not go back to that Activity (the one that gets the users full name).

How do I get the full name I read in as a String from an EditText in another Activity? I called finish() already on the Activity that gets the fullname by the time I need that String.

I hope it was clear what I meant this time. If not, I'll try to explain differently again. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: store in database and retrieve it when activity resumes. Use shared preferences.

Comment: Your problem is not clear ,make it clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to save your Userinput in sharedprefrences.

```
private void SavePreferences(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private void LoadPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String score = sharedPreferences.getString("INPUT", "");

}
```

To save your Userinput simply call SavePreferences("INPUT", "YOUR_Input"); And to retreive it call the LoadPreferences().